# Query on object and send data to external system

Tags: data-export

i have a requirement of query on a object lets say "lead " there may be 30-40 fields on it and then send it to external application (java) and eventually ftp site..can i use below approach...

1)query the data from apex code , put it in json format and send the json object the service exposed by external system like java?
2)use bulk api and develop it using java , authenticate into salesforce,query and create csv and then ftp?

need help on if 1 is achievable?

Comment: 1 is fine, 2 there is no FTP into salesforce

Answer (score 2):

Sending data to the external system is trivial:

```
Lead[] leads = [SELECT Fields FROM Lead WHERE SomeCriteria];
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint('callout:myendpoint');
req.setBody(JSON.serialize(leads));
HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
```

Keep in mind you'll need to set a Remote Site setting, and for this example, you'd use a Named Credential. You can also use a normal URL, like "http://myserver.com/myservice/receivedata".

Your service must be Internet-facing in order to receive the data from Salesforce.

Comment: thanks sfdcfox , but what about if my lead has thousands of records? is this still a viable option?